# Apache spark + confluent platform integration and writing to hdfs files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hdfs

I am using spark streaming to process data from confluent platform and writing to hdfs after making few transformations to records.
I have configure the spark cluster 16 executor and 4cores per executor And Kafka setup is a topic with 72 partitions.

The issue which am facing is, it is always one single executor is writing all records to hdfs.
I have confirmed this from spark UI and executing Kafka cli command for describing consumer groups for my kafa topic reveals only one unique host address is connected to kafka from spark cluster.

So my application is not scaling horizontal irrespective of any increase in spark cluster and Kafka cluster.

Sample  rough code.

```
Dstream ds = kutils.createdirectstream (locationstrategies.preferconsistent,topics,params);

Dt= Ds converted to dataset by applying schema;

Dt.write hdfs .mode append .format parquet;
```

Sorry I don't have access to real code. the above is just a template.

Kindly help.

Comment: Have you considered using Kafka Connect to write to HDFS? That would enable you scale that component of the processing easily.

Comment: Hi Robin,
Thanks for your suggestion.
But We have a transformation layer logic in between which entiches data by lookup  and formats and etc..so we had introduced spark streaming process layer..

Comment: sure, but you can write the results of your streaming back to Kafka, and then from Kafka Connect to HDFS.